# Mongodb query - check existing documents

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to write a code in Ruby such that if a document already exists in my database to do an aggregation of the new document and the one that already exists, and if it does not exist add the new document to the database ?

I know how to do an aggregation, but I don't know how to use $exists in this case.

To update existing documents, i've founded, but I think that I can't use it if I want to push a whole hash:

```
db.coll.update({"title" : "Document"},
 {$push:{"comments":{
     "user":'user2',
     "message": 'My second comment',
     "dateCreated": new Date(2013,11,10,2,35),
     "like": 0
}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `upsert: true` option in your update query.

From the mongodb manual:

> Upsert: If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.

Your query could look something like this:

```
db.coll.update({"title" : "Document"}, {$push: {
    "comments":{
        "user":'user2',
        "message": 'My second comment',
        "dateCreated": new Date(2013,11,10,2,35),
        "like": 0
        }
    },
    {upsert: true}
})
```